# Force git to clone submodules using https protocol

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I have a git project with a submodule as a dependency which in turn has others submodules dependencies.

Those sub/submodules are configured to be cloned using `ssh` but my Jenkins must use `https`.

(Unfortunately I can't change submodules configs)
(Unfortunately I can't change Jenkins)

Is there any way to tell git to clone submodules (and their submodules) using https only?

Comment: There is no universal ssh to https converter for git urls, it really depends on your host. WHy not add a ssh key to your jenkins, as it allows quicker revocation when it gets leaked/hacked

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change Jenkins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Urls can be overriden by this:

```js
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf 'git@github.com:'
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to avoid `--global` but still let sub/submodules use `https` over `git`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment yet and there is slight mistake in the first answer.
Do not use ', instead use " or nothing at all.
so the config could look something like this:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "git@github.com:"
```

You can check result of your change using: `config --global --list`
If you use ', it will be in final config and probably won't match.

Comment: On windows this worked, and Hitmands did not